# How to stop projects with compilation error being checked to SVN

Tags: svn, teamcity, tortoisesvn

Ok I'm working in a build management role using C# , team city and SVN
and the devs keep checking in code with compilation errors. I'm assuming that the dev's compile their code on there local machines before checking and it succeeds. But there obviously has been a missing **add** in SVN.  Is there any way or tool to prevent this ?

Thanks

Aidan

Comment: From the Subversion side, you could create a `pre-commit` hook that triggers code compilation and rejects the submission if errors are found. But it's a terrible idea because it'll just slow down everybody's work. I'm not familiar with TeamCity but I understand that the intended flow is to verify code *after* being committed and send the appropriate alerts.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know how is to make create a build bot you submit changes (rather than committing to trunk) and then only allowing the build bot to update trunk (trunk is read only for everyone else). That means developers, instead of running `svn up` to get changes from trunk, will be running `svn merge ^/your/trunk` to get the latest changes.

Here's a high level overview of the steps:

- Setup an area for per-developer work for the project. For example, if `^/proj/trunk` is trunk, then `^/proj/users` could contain a directory for each user. This is where developers do their work. When they want to update from trunk, they run `svn merge ^/proj/trunk`. When they want to submit to trunk, they commit to their user directory.
- Setup a build bot and an svn user for the build bot.
- Use a [start-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) to limit commits to trunk to anyone but the build bot svn user.
- Optionally use a [start-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) to limit commits to each user directory in `^/proj/users` to only the user whose name matches the directory.
- Write a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) that monitors `^/proj/users` kicks off a build bot build every time there is a change. You might want ignore commits that are only a result from merging from `^/proj/trunk` to reduce the number of builds.
- If the build bot succeeds, the build bot svn user merges the change into trunk. On failure, the developer who wrote the code that is failing should get a notification.

Comment: Thank you Doug for your comprehensive answer